# Declaring war when enemy spy is killed. Which is the warmonger penalty?

Tags: civilization-5

In **Civilization V**, whenever you catch a spy trying to steal a technology and identify who his master is, you are presented with three options.

**1. To forgive them for spying on you**

Which gives a diplomatic boost with that civilization.

**2. To ask them to stop spying on you**

Which results in a diplomatic penalty with that civilization.

**3. To declare war**

Warring is often difficult due to the warmonger penalties. I know that whenever one declares war on a civ teaming with another through *'Should we declare war on...?'*, the warmonger penalty is [halved](http://www.carlsguides.com/strategy/civilization5/war/).

> Know that the Warmonger Penalty is cut in half any time you have agreed to go to War against a Civ at another's request, or asked them to do this through the Diplomacy interface (Shall we declare war upon...).

**Question:**

Is the warmonger penalty for declaring war upon discovering a spy, reduced by the fact that you just caught them spying?

Answer (score 2):

Put simply: no.

Every time you declare war on a Civ you gain 250 flat warmongering "points". This is just a raw value that represents your warmongering level which is then adjusted for individual Civs based off of their leader's warmongering-hate level.

Sort of interested in your source for the team war declaration causing halved warmongering - it's my understanding that you simply get a flat warmongering score from declaring war, however the city capturing points can get halved based off of war statuses between civs.

Comment: The source for that halved-warmongering quote is this page: http://www.carlsguides.com/strategy/civilization5/war/

Comment: It's in the link in the word 'halved'. If it's confusing, how should I reformat it?